# Read sql queries in python

Tags: python, mysql-python

I am a little lost in something I am trying to do. Learning how to run sql within Python.

I have a db in in Python sqlite with three tables 1, 2, 3.

I then have a series of several queries I have written in a .sql file.

I have a loop created, but I am missing a step to read and execute the sql file.

```
# For each of the 3 tables, query the database and print the contents
for table in ['1', '2', '3']:

# Plug in the name of the table into SELECT * query
result = c.execute("SELECT * FROM %s;" % table);

# Get all rows.
rows = result.fetchall();

# \n represents an end-of-line
print "\n--- TABLE ", table, "\n"
```

My sql queries are written in a separate .sql file called queries.sql. Where do I put it in the loop?

Answer (score 1):

Do post your sql queries to help you better. But looping is easily done this this -

```
#before the loop create mysql client & 
#create cursor to mysql server

for sql_query_template in open(sql_queries_file,'r'):
    result = c.execute(sql_query_template % table);
    rows   = result.fetchall();
    print 'Rows Fetched: %d' % len(rows)
```

I hope you get the idea...

Comment: I am getting the idea. I have reproduced the above, but getting the error "Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
NameError: name 'table' is not defined"

Comment: @mylesg This chunk of code should be added to yours, variables like the file name set, and then indented inside your `for table` loop, along with the rest of the commands, so that `table` is defined by your loop.

Comment: @mylesg you need to customized this code to fit yours. I dont know what `table` is. eventually `table` is a variable having the table name you want to perform queries on.